# Binding Google Service Account with Kubernetes Cluster Service Account in GKE cluster across GCP projects

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've built a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster in a GCP project.

According to the different use cases of applications running on the cluster, I associated the applications with the different service accounts and the different granted permissions. To do so, I bound Google Service Account (GSA) with the Kubernetes Cluster Service Account (KSA) as follows:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[K8S_NAMESPACE/KSA_NAME]" \
  GSA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

```
kubectl annotate serviceaccount \
  --namespace K8S_NAMESPACE \
  KSA_NAME \
  iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=GSA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#option_2_node_pool_modification

Everything I have explained works normally.

Currently, there are many GKE clusters in different projects. Furthermore, the service accounts assigned with the applications are supposed to be created in the same project that hosts the GKE clusters. I am planning to do the GSA centralisation for KSA into one GCP project.

**Questions**

1. Would it be possible to build a GKE cluster in a project and create a GSA for an application running on the GKE cluster in another project?
2. If so, what roles do I have to grant the GSA associated with the GKE cluster? in order to access the GSAs in the other project and bind them with KSA.

*Note*: This thread is only about the **Google Service Account (GSA) associated with the application running on a GKE cluster**, not about the Google Service Account (GSA) associated with the GKE cluster.

And about **how to bind Google Service Account (GSA) in a GCP project with Kubernetes Cluster Service Account (KSA) in the GKE cluster in another GCP project**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* be possible.  You can definitely create service accounts in one project and attach them to resources in another project.

In the project which "hosts" your service account(s):

- ensure that the `iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage` constraint is NOT enforced for the project (this is done by [updating the organization policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts#setting_boolean_constraint) for the project)
- I believe you will also need to grant `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` to the GSA associated with each cluster as well.

See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-different-project

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I'll try your suggestion and get back to you with the feedback.